# A question about vector function second order gradient.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a question about some vector function’s gradient twice, I tried for days but cant figure it please help me? Please explain it as clear as possible. Thank you very much!

---

$\mathbf x$ is vector $(x,y,z)^T$, $\mathbf q_{\,i}$ and $\mathbf v_{i}$ are some constant vector, $\mathbf h$ is a constant number. 
$$
\theta_{\displaystyle\mathbf q_{i}}(\mathbf x)=\exp\left(\dfrac{-\|\mathbf x-\mathbf q_i\|^2}{h^2}\right).               \\ \, \\ \, \\
n(\mathbf x)=\dfrac{\displaystyle  \sum_{\mathbf q_i\in Q}\mathbf v_i\theta_{\mathbf q_i}(\mathbf x)}
{\displaystyle\left\|\sum_{\mathbf q_i\in Q}\mathbf v_i\theta_{\mathbf q_i}(\mathbf x)\right\|},
$$
Now what I want is the expression below $$\nabla^T\nabla n(\mathbf x)(\mathbf x-\mathbf q_{\,i})$$
Would you please help me? Please explain it as clear as possible. Thank you very much!